# filter an XML file by atributes and display result in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a program that stores the name, author, and ISBN of a book in a XML file. The program works, but I have problem with the search button, it only filter by the whole, but I need it to filter by any word.

I have been searching, and I found this:

```
private void FilterByType(string type)
{
            var dataView = ((DataTable) this.dataGridView.DataSource).DefaultView;
            dataView.RowFilter = "(Type = '" + type + "')";
}
```

and this:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "(Type LIKE *'" + substring + "*')";
```

The first one works, but like I said it looks for the whole name, and when I try to use the second one I get this message "Syntax error: Missing operand before'*' operator".

Hope you can help me, and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misplaced the `*`. It should be

```
 "(Type LIKE '*" + substring + "*')"; //moved after the '
```

Complete [reference here.](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

Comment: Wow I really need to pay more attention to little things lol. Thanks a lot!